# XML to csv conversion using python xml library

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Sorry if this question is already asked.
I have below XML file for which i want to convert it into CSV or excel.
Here i want to extract NodeName and its child DestIPAddress under IpRoutelist. and Value under Custom/Name tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <EnbConfigGetResponse xmlns="http://Airspan.Netspan.WebServices">
            <EnbConfigGetResult>
                <ErrorCode>OK</ErrorCode>
                <NodeResult>
                    <NodeResultCode>OK</NodeResultCode>
                    <NodeName>IMUMB0899</NodeName>
                    <NodeDetail>
                        <Custom>
                            <Name>Circle</Name>
                            <Value>MU</Value>
                        </Custom>
                        <Custom>
                            <Name>GW VLAN 601</Name>
                            <Value>2405:200:101::</Value>
                        </Custom>
                        <Custom>
                            <Name>GW VLAN 602</Name>
                            <Value>2405:200:104::</Value>
                        </Custom>
                    </NodeDetail>
                    <EnbConfig>
                        <Name>IMUMB0899</Name>
                        <Hardware>1000 SFP</Hardware>
                        <Description>TT</Description>
                        <Site>DND</Site>
                        <Region>DND</Region>
                        <Altitude>0</Altitude>
                        <NbifEventAlarmForwarding>Enabled</NbifEventAlarmForwarding>
                        <ENodeBType>Macro</ENodeBType>
                        <ENodeBID>397063</ENodeBID>
                        <M1SubnetMask>120</M1SubnetMask>
                        <IpRouteList>
                            <IpRoute>
                                <DestIpAddress>172.172.6.20</DestIpAddress>
                                <IpSubnetMask>255.255.255.255</IpSubnetMask>
                                <GatewayIpAddress>172.21.200.1</GatewayIpAddress>
                            </IpRoute>
                            <IpRoute>
                                <DestIpAddress>2405:20:1::</DestIpAddress>
                                <IpSubnetMask>40</IpSubnetMask>
                                <GatewayIpAddress>2405:20:101:4:7:2:61:1</GatewayIpAddress>
                            </IpRoute>
                        </IpRouteList>
                <NodeResult>
     </EnbConfigGetResult>
        </EnbConfigGetResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried below code which extract the Name and IProute, but when i try to merge tham only one IP route i get against NodeName but two are available.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import lxml
import xml.etree.cElementTree
import openpyxl
import inspect
import os

sites = "xml"

with open(sites, "r",encoding='unicode_escape') as f:
    xml_data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "xml")

tag1 = input("Enter tagname1:")
tag2 = input("Enter tagname2:")

data = []
dd = []

for td in soup.find_all(tag1):
    data.append({"NodeName": td.text})
    
for iproute in soup.find_all(tag2):
    dd.append({"IpRoute": iproute.text})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dd)
    
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)
    
df.to_excel(sites + '.xlsx', sheet_name='Detail', index = False)
print("*************Done*************")
```

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: What do you enter for `tag1` and `tag2`? Also, why are you storing your results in two separate data structures (`data` and `dd`), then merging them later? Don't you want to keep everything together?

Comment: Your xml is invalid; can you edit your question and correct it?

Comment: @MattDMo i need the output as shown in snapshot.
And i enter tag1=NodeName and tag2 = DestIpAddress

Comment: @JackFleeting Its a part of big xml file, i edited thi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
# xml = utils.getFileContent('file.xml')
xml = ''' Your xml string'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
lstNodeResult = doc.selects('NodeResult')
data = [['NodeName','DestIpAddress','GatewayIpAddress','value1','value2','value3']]
for result in lstNodeResult:
    lstCustom = result.selects('NodeDetail>Custom')
    if lstCustom:
        lstCustom = lstCustom.Value.text
    NodeName = result.NodeName.text
    lstIpRoute = result.IpRoutes
    for IpRoute in lstIpRoute:
        row = [NodeName,IpRoute.DestIpAddress.text,IpRoute.GatewayIpAddress.text]
        if lstCustom: row.extend(lstCustom)
        data.append(row)
# print (data)
utils.save2csv('test.csv',data)

# Or
data = {
    'NodeName':lstNodeResult.NodeName.text,
    'DestIpAddress':lstNodeResult.select('IpRoute>DestIpAddress>text()'),
    'GatewayIpAddress':lstNodeResult.select('IpRoute>GatewayIpAddress>text()')
}
# print (data)
```

Result:

```
.......
I-MU-NVMB-OSC-0900-SMC004,2405:200:310:5a::,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:3503
I-MU-NVMB-OSC-0900-SMC004,2405:200:310:1::,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:3503
I-MU-NVMB-ISC-0181-SWC0002,2405:200:310:1::,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03,MU,2405:200:101:500:7:2:601:5d03,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03
I-MU-NVMB-ISC-0181-SWC0002,2405:200:311:2::,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03,MU,2405:200:101:500:7:2:601:5d03,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03
I-MU-NVMB-ISC-0181-SWC0002,2405:200:310:a152::,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03,MU,2405:200:101:500:7:2:601:5d03,2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03
.......
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Delete blank lines.

```
def delEmptyRows(name, encoding="utf-8"):
    lines = utils.getFileLines(name, encoding=encoding)
    lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()!='']
    utils.saveFile(name, "".join(lines), encoding=encoding)
# use
delEmptyRows('test.csv')
```

Method of obtaining IBridge2RfStatsRow data.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
xml = req.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/SWhDM1zq')

rows = []
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
lstIBridge2RfStatsRow = doc.selects('IBridge2RfStatsRow').children
# Add header
header = []
for col in lstIBridge2RfStatsRow[0]:
    header.append(col.tag)
rows.append(header)

# Generate line
for row in lstIBridge2RfStatsRow:
    rows.append([col.text for col in row])

utils.save2csv('IBridge2RfStatsRow.csv',rows)
```

Comment: Hey @dabingsou Thanks for your response, but there are multiple destIP against each NodeName., how to make that work?

Comment: @SunilSharma The number of these destIP is not fixed. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I need all destIP against each NodeName. Like NodeName1 -destip1               NodeName1-destip2 NodeName1 -destip3   NodeName2-destIp1 and so on

Comment: @SunilSharma I updated the answer. Do you think it helps?

Comment: @dbingsu, i also need all values inside 'CUSTOM' tag in 3 columns against NodeName.pls support
```<NodeDetail>
                <Custom>
                      <Name>Circle</Name>
                       <Value>MU</Value>
              </Custom>
             <Custom>
                       <Name>GW VLAN 601</Name>
                        <Value>2405:200:101:500:7:2:601:5d03</Value>
            </Custom>
            <Custom>
                   <Name>GW VLAN 602</Name>
                    <Value>2405:200:101:500:7:2:602:5d03</Value>
               </Custom>
           </NodeDetail>```

Comment: @SunilSharma Can you give an example of your part of XML and the desired results?

Comment: i have uploaded the sample XML here, which is having Custom , desired output is in Question snapshot Value1, value2 value3 https://pastebin.com/eCPJZRw5

Comment: Thanks Allot, really good to learn this library :).

Comment: whenever i create a csv and opening in i see there is a blank line after each row. Please check how to fix this, i am using windows server.

Comment: @SunilSharma I don't have a good way. I added a method to call it when you need to delete the last empty line.

Comment: @SunilSharma You mean there's a blank line after each row. It's a little strange. I'll check it.

Comment: @SunilSharma This problem does exist in windows. I haven't found a good way. Temporarily added a method to delete empty lines.

Comment: @daingsou Need your help to extract data inside the "IBridge2RfStatsRow" tag, and having 96 such tags. i have loaded the xml here https://pastebin.com/SWhDM1zq.

Comment: @SunilSharma I have updated the answer and you can see if it is what you want.

Comment: Thankyou very much, one thing i forgot to ask how to add Name column which will be unique for each "StatisticsResult" tag. in this example its  <Name>C5xFT11</Name>

Comment: @SunilSharma name = doc.select('StatisticsResult>Name>text()')

Answer (score 1):

There are certain things you have missed to consider in your code - like you are just doing a `soup.find_all('NodeName')` - which gives `all nodenames` present in the `xml` and `soup.find_all('DestIPAddress')` gives `all destipaddresses` present in the `xml` - how will you map them if you do it that way ?

Try this code, I have made `outer loop` to go through each `noderesult` - and `inner loop` to go through each `destipaddress` , i am assuming that `nodename` will be single for each `noderesult` hence using that same name for every `destipaddress` found in a particular `noderesult` :

```
tag1 = "NodeName"
tag2 = "DestIpAddress"

tag1_list = []
tag2_list = []

for node_res in soup.find_all('NodeResult'):
    
  for tg2 in node_res.find_all(tag2):
      tag1_list.append(soup.find(tag1).text)
      tag2_list.append(tg2.text)

print(tag1_list)
print(tag2_list)

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'NodeNames': tag1_list,
  'IpRoute': tag2_list
})
    
print(df)
```

DF-output :

```
   NodeNames       IpRoute
0  IMUMB0899  172.172.6.20
1  IMUMB0899   2405:20:1::
```

You can add the `write-excel` line in the end .

Comment: Thanks it worked well, i missed one thing i also need `GatewayIpAddress` against each nodename.
And Nodename is single for each Noderesult

Comment: hope you got an idea how to add new items from `xml` to `df`

Comment: Thanks, i got the idea i worked on pandas, but xml is bit new for me

Comment: The NodeName in output is coming same for all xml, its taking first NodeName for full xml.

Comment: Please check if you can help on this.
https://0bin.net/paste/HOf-mVMg#bLRgpGfbezBNX8wrO-MW/OsBaS3yVqqi6CjoqvTfrsM

Comment: the link doesn't open

Comment: there's a mistake in my answer - `tag1_list.append(soup.find(tag1).text)` should be changed to `tag1_list.append(node_res.find(tag1).text)`  -  then you'll get the proper node-name .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with xml and importing lxml, you might as well use it with xpath.

Note that the xml in your question is invalid (even after the editing) and this answer assumes the example was properly edited to be valid.

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

soap = """[your xml above, fixed]"""
doc = etree.XML(soap.encode())
columns = ['NodeName','DesIPAdd','GIPAdd','Value1','Value2','Value3']
ns = {'xx' : "http://Airspan.Netspan.WebServices"}
nodes = doc.xpath('//xx:NodeResult', namespaces=ns)
rows = []
for node in nodes:        
    sub_nodes = node.xpath('//xx:EnbConfig/xx:IpRouteList/xx:IpRoute', namespaces=ns)    
    for sub_node in sub_nodes:
        row = []
        row.append(node.xpath('//xx:NodeName/text()', namespaces=ns)[0])        
        row.append(sub_node.xpath('.//xx:DestIpAddress/text()', namespaces=ns)[0])
        row.append(sub_node.xpath('.//xx:GatewayIpAddress/text()', namespaces=ns)[0])
        row.extend(node.xpath('//xx:NodeDetail/xx:Custom/xx:Value/text()', namespaces=ns))
        rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
      NodeName    DesIPAdd      GIPAdd              Value1  Value2      Value3
0   IMUMB0899   172.172.6.20    172.21.200.1           MU   2405:200:101::  2405:200:104::
1   IMUMB0899   2405:20:1::     2405:20:101:4:7:2:61:1  MU  2405:200:101::  2405:200:104::
```

Comment: I tried this with my xml file, instead of 997 rows, i get 60894 rows, so something happen in the loop,and NodeName is same for all rows. i have loaded part of xml on below 
https://0bin.net/paste/HOf-mVMg#bLRgpGfbezBNX8wrO-MW/OsBaS3yVqqi6CjoqvTfrsM

Comment: @SunilSharma I took a quick look at the xml; if I were you, I would give up on the idea of converting it to pandas (or whatever). I would stick with the native xml environment, learn xpath and xquery, use tools like BaseX and go from there.

Comment: Yeah but this the requirement, thats why need to convert it into csv.